# jade. Обработка тега, полученного из переменной

Tags: jade

Здравствуйте. Есть такая разметка, написанная на jade.

```
- var tag = "div";

#{tag}(class = "someclass")
```

Работает все нормально. Проблема возникает, если тег в переменной самозакрывающийся. То есть разметка ниже работает некорректно.

```
- var tag = "input";

#{tag}(class = "someclass")
```

Вопрос - как заставить jade определять какой тег закрывать, а какой нет?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась просто, но не так красиво, как хотелось бы

```
- var tag = "input"
- var selfclosing = 1;
- var voidElements = {"area":1,"base":1,"br":1,"col":1,"embed":1,"hr":1,"img":1,"input":1,"keygen":1,"link":1,"menuitem":1,"meta":1,"param":1,"source":1,"track":1,"wbr":1};

if voidElements[tag]
    #{tag}()/
else
    #{tag}()
```